# A conflict exists with definition in namespace internal

Tags: actionscript-3

Hey I know this question has been asked before but people there have different issues.

So here is my simple code, this program will show the symbol i have created for each day according to day it is today.

```
    var day:Date = new Date();
       var today:int = day.day;

       //trace(day);

   function addpic(){

    switch(today){

                    case 1:
                    {
                        var pic:Monday = new Monday();
                        addChild(pic);
                        pic.x = 640;
                        pic.y = 200;
                    }
                    break;

                    case 2:
                    {
                        var pic:Tuesday = new Tuesday();
                        addChild(pic);
                        pic.x = 640;
                        pic.y = 200;
                    }
                    break;

                    case 3:
                    {
                        var pic:Wednesday = new Wednesday();
                        addChild(pic);
                        pic.x = 640;
                        pic.y = 200;
                    }
                    break;

                    case 4:
                    {
                        var pic:Thurday = new Thursday();
                        addChild(pic);
                        pic.x = 640;
                        pic.y = 200;
                    }
                    break;

                    case 5:
                    {
                        var pic:Friday = new Friday();
                        addChild(pic);
                        pic.x = 640;
                        pic.y = 200;
                    }
                    break;


                    case 6:
                    {
                        var pic:Saturday = new Saturday();
                        addChild(pic);
                        pic.x = 640;
                        pic.y = 200;
                    }
                    break;

                    case 7:
                    {
                        var pic:Sunday = new Sunday();
                        addChild(pic);
                        pic.x = 640;
                        pic.y = 200;
                    }
                    break;  

        }

     }

     addpic();
```

I think its cause I declared pic variable multiple times but didn't I declare it in a case, so it shouldn't do that right?

Answer (score -1):

You should do like that:

```
var pic:*;

function addpic():void
{
    switch (today)
    {
        case 1 :
            pic = new Monday();
            break;
        case 2 :
            pic = new Tuesday();
            break;
        case 3 :
            pic = new Wednesday();
            break;
        case 4 :
            pic = new Thursday();
            break;
        case 5 :
            pic = new Friday();
            break;
        case 6 :
            pic = new Saturday();
            break;
        case 7 :
            pic = new Sunday();
            break;
    }
    pic.x = 640;
    pic.y = 200;
    addChild(pic);
}

addpic();
```

Or more simple, with a movie Clip "pic" (Pic class) containing your days (7 frames):

```
var pic:Pic = new Pic();
pic.x = 640;
pic.y = 200;
addChild(pic);

function addpic():void
{
    pic.gotoAndStop(today);
}

addpic();
```

Comment: Showing all the wrong ways to do it. Voted down. pic should just be a MovieClip type, why making it untyped?